# How to disable a particular customer account without deleting the record from the table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to give customers an option to delete/deactivate their account if they wish to. However, I don't want to remove the data from the table. Instead, I want to retain the customer data but they should no longer be able to sign in unless they 'reactivate' their account using some steps not important right now.

Comment: Why not create a customer attribute `is_active` and check that in an observer for the `custome_login` event

Answer (score 0):

create module like below:

[image]

create custom attribute active_status for customer entity:
files are as under:

registration.php

```
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ramasha_CustoemrStatsus',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ramasha_CustoemrStatsus',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ramasha_CustoemrStatsus" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer instance="Ramasha\CustoemrStatsus\Observer\Frontend\Customer\Login" name="ramasha_custoemrstatsus_observer_frontend_customer_login_customer_login"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php


namespace Ramasha\CustoemrStatsus\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'active_status', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Active Status',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'active_status')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Observer/Frontend/Customer/Login.php

```
<?php


namespace Ramasha\CustoemrStatsus\Observer\Frontend\Customer;

class Login implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        //Your observer code
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        echo $customer->getName(); //Get customer name
// here you can get customer that custom attribute
var_dump($customer->getActiveStatus());
// and on above status you can take your business logic need to keep customer of logout. 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note this is just hint module what kind of event you suit best for customer use them